# Prevalence of ATMs that accept JCB cards

Tags: china, payment-cards, south-korea, taiwan, atms

I was surprised that Tigerair does not accept [JCB cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCB_Co.,_Ltd.), and I am starting to worry that it might be difficult to get any cash from ATMs using my JCB card outside of Japan.

Outside of Japan, are JCB cards accepted by all ATMs, or only a portion of them, or like only at a particular bank in each capital city?

I am especially interested in Taiwan/China/Korea, but information for other countries also very appreciated.

Comment: Reading the wiki article, it sounds like they won't be accepted outside of markets where cards are offered, or the few (like the US) where they have negotiated deals with another network. I certainly don't think you'd get anywhere with them in Europe.

Comment: In Europe, JCB cards are at least not commonly accepted, but with some luck, you might be abel to use the JCB card in e.g. upper class stores.

Comment: The [JCB site](http://www.jcb.co.jp/cashing/service/type/overseas/) seems to says you can use it at ATMs which display the Cirrus logo.

Comment: Can you split your question into three - Taiwan, China and Korea?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to require the Japan tag as you are explicitly asking about countries outside of Japan.

Comment: I am unsure why you thought Tigerair not accepting JCB was a surprise, however the JCB whilst not being as widespread as Visa/MasterCard/American Express, is still able to be used at any ATM in the world that features a JCB, JCB Cards or Cirrus logo. ATMs that display this are available in countries such as Taiwan, Hong Kong, South Korea, China, Australia, Russia, UAE, US, UK, Italy, France, Germany, Spain, Austria, Denmark (and more), however not all ATMs/vendors in a country accept the JCB card and your mileage may vary.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder: Thanks for the tips! Maybe you could make this an answer, if you have a rough idea about the number of ATMs that feature these logos (one per country? one per city? about one per train station?)

Comment: Comments added and compiled into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

#### Not all ATMS around the World accept JCB cards, however the number of ATMs that do is increasing

JCB cards, whilst not being as widespread as Visa / MasterCard / American Express, are still able to be used at any ATM in the world that features a JCB, JCB Cards or Cirrus logo. ATMs that display this are available in countries such as Taiwan, Hong Kong, South Korea, China, Australia, Russia, UAE, US, UK, Italy, France, Germany, Spain, Austria, Denmark (and more), however not all ATMs/vendors in a country accept the JCB card and your mileage may vary. It appears also, that the cards are accepted by certain banks (and their ATMs) rather than non-specific ATMs.

Currently worldwide coverage is increasing (according to the increasing number of [JCB monthly press releases](http://www.global.jcb/en/press/)).

The JCB website itself does not manage a list of ATMs (at least not on
either their Global or Japanese websites), however the periodic press
releases seem to mention which banks provide JCB card service.
For example:

> **OCT 14, 2016: Bank Saint Petersburg to Start Accepting JCB Cards;**
>   "...The bank network includes 7,100 POS terminals and 700 ATMs located not only in Saint Petersburg but also throughout the Leningrad region, in Moscow and Kaliningrad."
>
> **SEP 26,2016: Bank of Bhutan to start accepting JCB Card;**
>   "With this launch, JCB cards are accepted at more than 480 locations and it covers 90% of POS terminals and ATMs in the market."

If you search specifically for the country you are looking to travel to, you should find a press release stating the JCB acceptance.

Global Website Search Page can be accessed [HERE](http://jcb.dga.jp/?PHPSESSID=&domain=global).

Answer (score 6):

[JCB's May 2016 World Report](http://www.global.jcb/en/businesses/card-issuing/world-report/pdf/WR_No.56.pdf) has a map of JCB *offices*:

[image: JCB offices]

While compatible ATMs might be available elsewhere, it is reasonable to imagine that at least one compatible ATM is available at each of these places. However, some countries have compatible ATMs but no JCB office.  Note the quasi-absence of offices from South/Central America and Africa, which presumably indicates a lower number of compatible ATMs in these areas. Actually this map is strikingly similar to the [main travel destinations of Japanese people](https://www.jata-net.or.jp/data/stats/2014/05.html), which makes sense after all.

The same document boasts 30 million merchants, but it is difficult to know what they list as a merchant, and a large proportion of these are probably in Japan.

In Taiwan, while paying at restaurants/stores was no problem, most ATMs refused my JCB card. I finally found a Standard Chartered ATM that accepted it and gave me some cash.

Comment: I think your assumptions to be correct, however you may find that not all countries that accept JCB cards have a representative office in country. Take Denmark or Bhutan for example.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder: Very true, I added that information in the body of the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In South Korea, look for a "Global ATM." It should be printed on a sign above the ATM. I have had issues with domestic ATMs not accepting my US ATM card here even though it was issued by MasterCard.

I can't guarantee that a Global ATM will accept your JCB card, but that will be your best chance.